# Modifying string using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to modify the following string using `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` in C#, and I need to replace `/(integer)x(integer)/` with `/`. For example in `url`, I need to replace `/1080x1080/` to `/`. How can I do this? I studied regex but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

```
string url = "https://scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/1080x1080/22158936_1794137857546339_3682912105310191616_n.jpg";
//The link is actually invalid because I modified it
```

Comment: See msdn for good reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match in following way :

```
/\d+x\d+/
```

Replace the matching with your replacing string.

In C#, you can use [Regex Replace method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) in following way :

```
string output = Regex.Replace("your_string", @"/\d+x\d+/", "/");
```

Comment: Oh it was much more simple than I thought... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the string using [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string url = "https://scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/1080x1080/22158936_1794137857546339_3682912105310191616_n.jpg";
url = Regex.Replace(url, @"/\d+x\d+/", "/");
```